# How customize a JQuery Slider like this two?

Tags: slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

1.
http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/standard-linear/operational-amplifiers-products.page
Column: "Slew Rate (Typ) (V/us)": It is a range slider, can have dynamic minimum/maximum value by other changing other criterian.

Column: "Vs (Min) (V)": It is a simple slider, can have dynamic minimum/maximum value by other changing other criterian.

The minimum/maximum value can display next to the slider.

2.
http://para.maximintegrated.com/en/search.mvp?fam=stepdn&270=Internal%20Pwr.%20FETs&tree=powersupplies

It is similar as last case, but the minimum/maximum value can display on the slider.

Does anyone can give me some directions to implements a slider like these two?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI Slider Documentaton](http://api.jqueryui.com/Slider/) clearly describes how to customize the slider as in the link.
See [Demo](http://jqueryui.com/Slider/).